# Parse.com iOS Query with Subquery doesn't work sometimes

Tags: ios, parse-platform

```
        let subQuery = PFUser.query()!
        let lang = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations[0] as! String
        subQuery.whereKey("lang", equalTo: lang)
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Enquiry")
        query.whereKey("owner", notEqualTo: user)
        query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("answer")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.whereKey("skipped", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        query.whereKey("owner", matchesQuery: subQuery)
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

The code above worked flawless in development with about 1000 records in the database. But not with more than 3000. There are many record that matches the query but **mostly** returns an error with `No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.8.1)`.
Removing the subquery fixes the problem. But I need to check for the right language. I thought, that one user record is missing a lang entry but they are all set. 
Why is the subquery not working properly? Can I fix it without an app update somehow with cloud code? Is this a parse sdk bug?

Comment: When you say records, how many users do you have and how many enquiries? And you are aware of the default limit of 100 items on the subquery?

Comment: There are 3500+ user records and 2500+ enquiries. I'm not aware about the 100 items limit on the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

(values correct at the time of writing)

Any query is limited to 100 return items by default, and you can optionally change that limit up to 1000.

So, your subquery is getting the first 100 users with the specified language and the default sort ordering. If those users don't have any non-skipped enquiries for the current user without an answer then the result set will be empty.

To verify this is the issue you can set the `limit` on the subquery to 1000. Note that it's still possible you won't get any results, but it forms a good base test.

It isn't a bug, though it isn't useful. It also isn't possible to fix without some code change.

In general you'll probably need to switch to cloud code so you can iterate through the users until you get to the end or find the requisite number of results to return. Cloud code will allow you to do this faster than the app could do and to change the logic in future without having to make another app release.

Comment: The subquery only check if the owners (a PFUser) lang field is for example "de". And it only queries for 1 record. I don't see a connection between the limited return items and the query.

Comment: How does it only query for 1 user?